# How to convert a field of dataframe into int in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my dataset, i have a feature (called Size) like this one:

```
import pandas as pd


dit={"Size" : ["0","0","5","15","10"] }
dt = pd.DataFrame(data=dit)
```

when i run `dt.info()` it gives me the below result:

```
Size                                     140 non-null object
```

However, i expect it to be `int`. When i try the below code:

```
dt.loc[:,"Size"] = dt.loc[:,"Size"].astype(int)
```

it complains with:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '
```

How can i convert `Size` to `int`?

Comment: Does `.to_numeric()` work for you?

Comment: Which pandas version do you use? I used your code exactly and got `Size    5 non-null int64`

Comment: dt['Size'] = dt['Size'].astype(int) - can you try this?

Comment: If I run the code, I get int like Tom too. Strange!

Comment: I perhaps got this when I ran `dt.info()` : `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 1 columns):
Size    5 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1)
memory usage: 120.0 bytes`

Comment: Could you try running this in `Jupyter Notebooks` or datalore.io?

Comment: ok, i edited my question. How about now?

Comment: I got this (*After your edit*) : `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 1 columns):
Size    5 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 120.0+ bytes`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change data type of columns in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-data-type-of-columns-in-pandas)

Comment: @RizaGul No way.

Answer (score 2):

Use `pd.to_numeric()` :-

```
dit={"Size" : ['0','0','5','15','10'] }
dt = pd.DataFrame(data=dit)
dt['Size'] = pd.to_numeric(dt['Size'])
dt.info()
```

**Output**

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 1 columns):
Size    5 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1)
memory usage: 120.0 bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have to select the column to be converted, use the .values to get the array containing all values and then use astype(dtype) to convert it to integer format.

```
dt['Size'].values.astype(int)
```